# jQuery Show/Hide Not Functioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to show one Tweet at a time and have it cycle through.  I have two types of pages, and on one page it works correctly, but the other they never show.  Is there some sort of CSS precedence rule that could be overriding it?

HTML:

```
<div class="twitterFeed">
    <p>Tweet here</p>
    <p>Tweet here</p>
    <p>Tweet here</p>
    <p>Tweet here</p>
    <p>Tweet here</p>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var currentTwitterItem = 4;
NextTwitterItem();

setInterval( NextTwitterItem, 8000);

function NextTwitterItem() {

    currentTwitterItem++;

    if (currentTwitterItem >= 5) {
        currentTwitterItem = 0;
    }

    $(".twitterFeed p").hide();
    $(".twitterFeed p:eq(" + currentTwitterItem + ")").show();

}
```

Comment: `currentTwitterItem` is not defined.

Comment: It is defined, I just forgot to put it in the question.  Code is corrected now.

Comment: Please see my answer. I think it's doing what you were asking. If not, please elaborate.

Comment: Look at houstonartsalliance.com/about/history in the sidebar, then look at houstonartsalliance.com (screen height needs to be > 950px to show).  It works on the subpage but not the main page. Markup is the same.

Comment: Well the counter seems to be working in both. Though in the main page you have an error. `Received message of type object from http://platform.twitter.com, expected a string`

Comment: Ok I think the problem is that you have multiple `.twitterDiv .news .twitterFeed` blocks on the main page because it's in a carousel. You might want to wrap that in an `each` so that it applies the change to ALL of the `.twitterDiv`s

Comment: Check my updated answer and fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var currentTwitterItem = 0
NextTwitterItem();

setInterval( NextTwitterItem, 8000);

function NextTwitterItem() {
    $(".twitterDiv").each(function(){
        $(this).find(".twitterFeed p").hide();
        $(this).find(".twitterFeed p").eq(currentTwitterItem).show();
    })

    if (currentTwitterItem >= 5) {
        currentTwitterItem = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        currentTwitterItem++;
    } 
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f64vsnyq/) to include multiple containers

Comment: That's it.  I have a sidebar in each horizontal screen.  Thanks.